# How do I navigate using tags in a personal copy of the vim documentation?

Tags: macvim, tags, navigation

As background: I am a beginner in VIM and I want to go through the built-in vim manual, but with my own copy (not the system copy) so that I can practice in the manual text as I go along  (I also bought the book Practical VIM and went through vimtutor).

To do this I went to the location where these manuals are located:

```
/usr/local/cellar/macvim/8.1-161/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/doc
```

and copied the contents to a directory in my documents directory:

```
sudo cp * ~/Documents/vim_learning/vim_doc
```

Now, I want to navigate this documentation using `ctl-]` and `ctl-o` but I can't in the versions I copied, and also when I just open a copy in the main `doc` folder using vim.  I get `E426 tag not found: foo` error. Of course can navigate like I want to when I use the `:help user-manual` command. To get around this I presumed that I had to tell vim to use the tags file tried adding `set tags=./tags;` to my vimrc, which I verified was working by adding and removing lines to change the color scheme. This did not work. Is there any quick way to make these navigation tags work?

I am running this vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Mar  3 2020 12:05:00)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-319
Compiled by travis@Traviss-Mac.local
```

and path_extra feature is enabled. 
I am running it in the mac terminal with this alias set in my .zshrc:

```
alias vi='mvim -v'
alias vim='mvim -v'
```

Comment: You'll need to run `:helptags [dir]`

Comment: I just tried this and it did not seem to work.

Comment: *"so that I can practice in the manual text as I go along"* Why would you want to practice on the documentation itself? It's really meant to be read and not modified... Not saying it's something you shouldn't be doing, just struck me as a bit odd... Anyways, I'll see if I can reproduce your issue and suggest a way to get tag navigation working.

Comment: Yeah it would kind of mirror how you edited the vimtutor as you go along.